# Pyspark : Reading csv files with fields having double quotes and comas

Tags: pyspark

I have a csv file which I am reading thru pyspark and loading into postgresql. One of its field is having strings which have coma and double quotes within the string. Like example below -

```
1. "RACER ""K"", P.L. 9"
2. "JENIS, B. S. ""N"" JENIS, F. T. ""B"" 5"
```

Pyspark is parsing it as below. Which is causing issue because it is mixing up the values/columns when I load the data into postgresql and script fail.

```
1. '\"RACER \"\"K\"\"'
2. '\"JENIS, B. S. \"\"N\"\" JENIS'
```

I am using spark 2.42. How can this situation be handled in pyspark?
Basically I want to program to ignore coma or double quotes if it is coming inside double quotes.

Comment: This worked for me - .option("quote", "\"")
.option("escape", "\"")

Answer (score 1):

You can try and remove the comma and double quotes using pandas before reading and loading into postgresql.

You can use [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.replace(r"[\"\',]", '')
```